# How to concatenate this json object using pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

This is my json data:

```
{location: {city: 'San Francisco', state: 'CA', country: 'USA'}}
```

I wanna see this:

```
{location_city: 'San Francisco', location_state: 'CA', location_country: 'USA'}
```

How to do like this using pandas?

Comment: You don't need pandas for this, please add more details as why you need pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a good reason for using pandas, one approach is to use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
import pandas as pd

res = pd.json_normalize( {'location': {'city': 'San Francisco', 'state': 'CA', 'country': 'USA'}}, sep="_")
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   location_city location_state location_country
0  San Francisco             CA              USA
```

Or, as an alternative you could write a function to flatten the dictionary:

```
def flatten_dict(d, sep="_", root=None):
    result = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        k = f"{root}{sep}{key}" if root else key
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            k = f"{root}{sep}{key}" if root else key
            result.update(flatten_dict(value, root=k))
        else:
            result[k] = value
    return result


res = flatten_dict({'location': {'city': 'San Francisco', 'state': 'CA', 'country': 'USA'}})
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'location_city': 'San Francisco', 'location_state': 'CA', 'location_country': 'USA'}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this:

```
import json

# 1. No pandas

json_data = '{"location": {"city": "San Francisco", "state": "CA", "country": "USA"}}'
json_data = json.loads(json_data)

res = {"{}_{}".format(k, k2): v2 for k, v in json_data.items() for k2, v2 in v.items()}

print(res)
# {'location_city': 'San Francisco', 'location_state': 'CA', 'location_country': 'USA'}


# 2. Use pandas 
print(pd.json_normalize(json_data, sep="_").to_json(orient="records"))
# [{"location_city":"San Francisco","location_state":"CA","location_country":"USA"}]
```